# updating firmware on arduino wifi shield

Tags: arduino-uno, wifi, firmware

I'm trying to upgrade firmware on my wifi shield by following the [upgrade instructions for Mac](http://arduino.cc/en/Hacking/WiFiShieldFirmwareUpgrading). I was wondering what this means?:

> Connect a jumper on the J3 connector, that put the shield in the programming mode. Then connect the USB cable to the shield USB mini socket

**How can I do this?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A "jumper" is a little piece of metal (or a 0-ohm resistor) that connects two pads or pins together. So, create an electrical connection across J3 ("DFU programming jumper" in all the pictures). You will then be able to program the shield via USB.

Comment: Ok so on the wifi shield i just place the cap over the DFU programming pin (the one that comes with the shield)? Like shown on this picture http://www.dfrobot.com/community/how-to-upgrade-arduino-wifi-shield-firmware-on-windows.html

Comment: That would be the one.

Answer (score 0):

The jumper is only neccesary if your device is not R3 (revision 3)
Be carefully if you connect the shield and your computer does not
recognice the port. 
You gonna need a driver in the link below there are all the steps
include other links to download software as Flip 3.4.7 who has 
the executable batchisp which one you can made the changes 
read the web site:

http://www.dfrobot.com/community/?p=3760

and extra information about that in official site of arduino
WiFi Shield Firmware Upgrading

there you gonna have an idea how to do it.

for me was more clear as in this site describe everything 
and also teach to probe if there is an update
having sucess in the process to installing something it
could be as a question answered with non the specific
thing you need.

http://www.binarytaskforce.com/Weblog/2013/09/21/arduino-wifi-firmware-update/

I am also in the process to update my device if I will have success 
I will write to how I do it. 
At the moment reading a bunch of differents forums beacuse arduino team itself
appearently had some troubles to provided a guided how to do it sucessfully.